# How to dynamically skin Polymer app

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

In a Polymer app I want to give the users the option to choose a certain theme from a set provided. So let's say that in a wrapper element I have a property called "*theme*" which holds a value like "*dark*", "*light*", etc. I would like to include a certain file with custom styles depending on that value.

So I have an element `my-app-wrapper` that includes some other ones if the user is not authenticated, or one called `my-app` for those that are. Now I tried to refactor it so that I have a new element called `my-app-dark` that extends `my-app` and just adds the import to the custom styles I need.

So in a file, let's say `dark.html` I have something like:

```
<custom-style>
  <style is="custom-style">
    html {
      --custom-theme: {
        --app-primary-color: #990AE3;
        --app-secondary-color: var(--paper-deep-orange-500);
      }
      ;
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

And in `my-app-wrapper` I have something like this:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[_equals(theme, 'dark')]]" restamp>
  <my-app-dark></my-app-dark>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="[[!_includes(themes, theme)]]" restamp>
  <my-app></my-app>
</template>
```

The problem here is that in the wrapper element I need to import both `my-app` and `my-app-dark`. So even if I have that if statement and I use `my-app` the custom style imported by `my-app-dark` is still loaded and it applies its styles.

My only restriction is that I can't use lazy imports and load the file with Polymer.importHref, but even if I could, the import would happen **after** the CSS rules are parsed so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented with theme changes with polymer 1.x using events and changing the theme programmatically.
In the main `may-app.html` file I set colors to variables in the host element:

```
<style include="shared-styles">
    :host {
         --some-color: black;
     }
</style>
```

These css color values were used throughout the child elements.
When a `change-theme` event was called, I used `this.customStyle['--some-color'] = 'white';` and `Polymer.updateStyles();` to apply the color change.

```
_onChangeTheme() {
    if (this.darkTheme) {
        //change to light theme
        this.customStyle['--some-color'] = 'white';
        this.set('darkTheme', false);
    } else {
        //change to dark theme
        this.customStyle['--some-color'] = 'black';
        this.set('darkTheme', true);
    }
    Polymer.updateStyles();
}
```

In Polymer 2 it should probably look something like this:

```
_onChangeTheme() {
    if (this.darkTheme) {
        //change to light theme
        this.updateStyles('--some-color','white');
        this.set('darkTheme', false);
    } else {
        //change to dark theme
        this.updateStyles('--some-color','black');
        this.set('darkTheme', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that `this. customStyle` is undefined (at least in Polymer 2).. but I will "dig deeper" based on this, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: following the link to the docs you sent to me in the Polymer slack channel (https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#use-updatestyles-instead-of-customstyle) I saw that I only need to call updateStyles with an object as a parameter, that has keys for the values I want to update.. so thanks a lot for your help, this + an AJAX call to get a theme-specific file did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just set a class on one of the top elements, and then use CSS.

```
<style>
  .some-top-element.dark {
    background-color: #000
    color: #fff;
  }

  .some-top-element.light {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
  }
</style>

<div class$="some-top-element [[theme]]">
```

Change the property `theme` to set a new CSS class. It's as simple as that. Do note the $ in the class property.